# Broken workflow: Undelete before edit

Tags: bug, questions, asking-questions

I have deleted a question of mine because I thought the information given is not complete enough.

Now I was trying to edit the question to make it better, but it says:

> You cannot edit your own deleted question. Undelete before editing.
> [image: Screenshot]

Shall I really make a bad question visible and risk downvotes and closing while editing the question into a better shape? I am tempted to post a new question instead, because this gives me unlimited time for research and formatting. However, it seems I can't even access the markdown source of the original question while the question is deleted.

Sure, I could start a new question, and just before posting, cut the markdown, undelete the original question, edit, paste and save. But is that really what we want people to do?

If I recall correctly, I can post a crappy answer and edit it while it's deleted. Why not for questions?

Comment: @JeanneDark: I can read that, but I don't understand it. Sounds like a technical restriction which could easily be resolved: `OnUndelete => deleted = false; if (editedSinceDeletion) bump();` The proposed workflow in the accepted answer is as cumbersome as I described it. It's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: But yeah, let's close it. Hasn't received attention for 7 years, so I guess I have to live with it. "Trivially" bypass ... let's do that then.

Comment: If you want to change how it works, you're going to have to submit a [meta-tag:feature-request]. This question as it stands is answered by the dupe.

Comment: There's a more recent [related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327788/348196) on Meta.SE. Robert Longson suggests the same workaround in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327789/348196). A few days ago, I posted [my own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367447/348196) there addressing the counterarguments with a refined proposal. Hopefully, it gets considered.